Display setting not saved
Just upgraded to 24.04.1 Set my monitor from 3840x2160 to 2560x1440 and find that when I shut off the monitor OR reboot, the display reverts to 3840x2160... I reset it to 2560x1440.  Happens every time. It doesn't "take".  Not a major problem, just a PITA...  No help online for newer versions...
TIA
